# Reduce the space above 'scrreprt's TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Is there a way to reduce the vertical space above the table of contents in the scrreprt?

Comment: Of course there is. For future reference, please post a small piece of code that can compile so community members can hit the ground running. It just helps both sides of the equation, really...

Comment: I'm a friend of quick solution (but i think its also a little dirty since I'm still inexperienced). So you could add a `\vspace{-5em}` right in front of `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: The heading of `tableofcontents` is set by `chapter*`. So the skip is the same as for other chapters. The command to manipulate this skip is `\chapterheadstartvskip`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel perhaps you should turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I linked a possible duplicated question.